# PHP CLI mode and Oracle charset?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, php

I'm using PHP with Oracle db through PDO_OCI with CL8MSWIN1251 charset. Anything working fine, when php requested by apache.
But, when i tryed to use php script from command line - i got data in wrong charset. Instead of text i got a lot of *?* symbols.
In both modes(CLI/Apache) php using same php.ini(/etc/php.ini).

Any suggestions how to fix?

**update**
Output of script are not printed on console. It written to file or posted via email, so command line charset doesnt matter.
Also, env variable NLS_LANG setted properly.

Comment: Maybe your command line character set doesn't support WIN1251?

Comment: No. Look at my question update please.